# как показать результат в Datagrid ? (Entity Framework)

Tags: c#, wpf, entity-framework

Есть таблица Выручка в базе данных SQLite.

| Id | Id_controller | Date | Sum |

и форме есть `Calendar` и `DataGrid`. При выборе в календаре любую дату мне нужно показать в `DataGrid` отчет по неделю от понедельника до пятницу и в конец итог. Ниже пример

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: `не мог решить или найти ответ` ответ на какой вопрос?

Comment: Как сделать запрос?

Comment: `db.Controller.ToList();` это вернет данные из БД

Comment: вы меня не так поняли

Comment: тогда переформулируйте вопрос, так как не понятно, что у вас за проблема

Comment: хочет написать запрос но не знает как написать запрос я так понял ?

Comment: Вы не умеете писать linq-запросы и sql-запросы? У вас достаточно сложный отчёт, к тому же многое про отчёт вы не сказали: это текущая неделя или любая неделя? Построить такой отчёт можно прямо на текущих данных, будет немного неоптимально по числу запросов (каждый день придётся отдельно запрашивать). В реальных системах (разделяют актуальную информацию, OLTP и архивную информацию с аналитикой, OLAP) подобные отчёты обычно предрассчитывают по закрытым финансовым дням.

Comment: любая выбранная неделя из 'Calendar'

Comment: Ну тогда представьте, что на вход отчёта вы подаете дату понедельника выбранной недели, в цикле семь раз прибавляете по одному дню и запрашиваете сводную цифру по дню. Такой вариант отчёта сможете сами сделать? Это будет неоптимально по ресурсам, втупую, но начнём с такого понимания задачи.